# Doesn't run errorLNK1120: 1 unresolved externals VS

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have these 2 simple classes. I have made a win32 app, but when i run it it shows me this error :

> Error 2   error LNK1120: 1 unresolved
>   externals C:\Users\D\Documents\Visual Studio Projects\LR3
>   SYSPROG\Debug\LR3 SYSPROG.exe 1   1   LR3 SYSPROG

I have tried it to run before it worked just fine how did i screw it up even with out touching it ?

```
    class Liquid
{
private:
    char *name;
    int density;
public:
    void CLperenaznachenie();
    //virtual void spiling();
public:
    char* get_name() const;
    void set_name(char const* new_name);
    int get_density() const;
    void set_density(int new_density);
};
class Alcohol:public Liquid
{
private:
    int fortress; 
public:
    void CAperenaznachenie();
    //void spiling(){
    //new stuff
    //};
public:
    int get_fortress() const;
    void set_fortress(int new_fortress);
};
```

Comment: Don't you get an error before the one you posted? From the doc:

Error LNK1120 gives you a count (number) of unresolved externals for this link. The conditions that cause unresolved externals are described with error LNK2001, which precedes this error message (once for each unresolved external).

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it by making it a console app and adding a main() function and that is what i need.